# Is my Arduino board defect? No matter what program I upload the pin 13 turns on and off 3 times and that's it

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

Just trying to find out if my Arduino UNO R1 board is broken or not.

First of all, everything seems normal, Arduino board shows "on" (green) when I plug it on my computer, I also can verify and upload programs to my Arduino board. But, no matter what program I upload the pin 13 turns on and off 3 times and that's it. I'm checkin it by using a LED. 
Eg. if I want to use another pin (ex. 7, 8, 12) it doesn't work, or even to write a program for turning on/off 9 times pin 13 doesn't work...

Note: I noticed that pin 8 turns the LED for less than a 1/2 a second.

I already tried to restart board by bridging the reset pin and also by pushing reset directly on the board, I also reinstalled Arduino Genuino Application. I thought to update Atmega8U2 firmware but accordingly to Arduino [site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) I don't need to update since I have firmware rev. 0.01.

It would be also great not to have to buy a new Arduino UNO. Thanks for your help

Edit:
Here is how I'm trying to make pin 12 work

```
int ledPin = 12;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the board is fine, but your programs are bad?

Comment: @Majenko that's also an possible. But I'm checking with a really basic tutorial. See my update please

Comment: And what do you have wired to pin 12?

Comment: The anode of a LED and the cathode to GND

Comment: No resistor? Maybe you are suffering from brownouts then.

Comment: Tried also with 220 ohms resistor. Yes I'm afraid it's broken

Comment: If it's broke you probably only need to replace the ATMega328, which is conveniently in a socket. Just make sure you buy one with the Arduino bootloader already programmed into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check if Arduino is working or not is to install Firmata. Here's the necessary steps:

1) Download Firmata application from the [official website](http://www.firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page#Firmata_Test_Program).

2) Connect Arduino to the computer

3) Open the Arduino IDE and burn the example Standard Firmata [File - Examples - Firmata - Standard Firmata]

4) Open the application, leaving the Arduino connected.

5) Chose the right serial port and debug every pin =D

Comment: So it turns out, that I was uploading my program to the wrong board. Thanks for the help!